# Incremental DOM doesn't work in nested ngFor

Tags: angular

I designed a simple array of objects to test the Angular Incremental DOM. It works when I add new value to the array (DOM only changes at the last position of the array), but when I try to change the value in the array, it re-renders the whole row once again, even I change only one item in the 1st object in the array.

See the gif below. 1st blink is `addRow()` 2nd, 3rd, 4th is `changeAmount()`.

```html
<button (click)="addRow()">Add row</button>
<button (click)="changeAmount()">Change 1st row amount</button>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of matrix">
            <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{row[column]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public columns = ["name", "value"];
  public matrix = [
    { name: "foo1", value: 1 },
    { name: "foo2", value: 2 },
    { name: "foo3", value: 3 },
    { name: "foo4", value: 4 }
  ];

  addRow(): void {
    const rand = this.randNumber(5, 50);
    this.matrix = [
      ...this.matrix,
      {
        name: "foo" + rand,
        value: rand
      }
    ];
  }

  changeAmount(): void {
    this.matrix = [
      ...this.matrix.map((v, k) => {
        if (k === 0) {
          return {
            ...v,
            value: this.randNumber(800, 3000)
          };
        }
        return v;
      })
    ];
  }

  private randNumber(min: number, max: number): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }
}
```

[image: DOM updates]

When I tried to add trackBy to the ngFor, it behaves the same (re-renders the whole `tr`).

How to improve given code to achieve result when only `<td>` changes when I hit changeAmount button. Is it even possible in nested `*ngFor`.
I can remove ChangeDtection.OnPush and modify the function to:

```js
changeAmount(): void {
  this.matrix[0].value = this.randNumber(800, 3000);
}
```

but I need this functionality when ChangeDetection.OnPush is turned on.

See [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ags4kw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this line inside `changeAmount2()` method..

```
this.matrix = [...this.matrix];
```

Basically, You need to change reference of Object while onPush strategy is on. so your method is...

```
changeAmount2(): void {
   this.matrix[0].value = this.randNumber(800, 3000);
   this.cdr.detectChanges();
   this.matrix = [...this.matrix];
}
```

Now, changes of property is detected by changeDetection.onPush().